# Several versions of Visual Studio Code?

Tags: mac

Im download VSC from official site and just drag it on "Applications".
Today im seen this:
[image]

What is this? Two versions of VSC?

P.S. More illustrative example:
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Ramhound It's pretty obvious to me. The icons on the far left and on the far right are both VSC icons. See my answer.

Comment: I just extract it from the zip packages. I don't install it from .msi. https://code.visualstudio.com/ Even also Wikipedia changes that icon. ([Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code))

Comment: David Postill's answer describes what the icons represent, but that still leaves the question of what is actually on that list (both new and old icons for the same app?  new app plus old app?).  I'm not a Mac user.  Can you right-click each icon and look at properties to see what each points to?  You could also click on each and see what opens.  The fix would depend on the result.

Comment: Im update post, with new pic.

Comment: It looks like you actually have both the new and old versions installed and accessible from icons.  If you want both for some reason (e.g., some apps only allow one instance open and this would give you access to two), leave it as is.  If you only need the newer one, you can uninstall the old one, or just delete the icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im close all VSC windows, open one, press Code -> check updates.

After restart i have only one (latest) version of VSC.

P.S. Sorry for english.

Comment: You may mark your own answer as the Accepted Answer.

Comment: After 19 hours =)

Answer (score 3):

#### What is this? Two versions of VSC?

That is hard to answer without knowing what program is attached to each of the icons.

What I can tell you is that icon on the left is the old VSC icon:

[image]

And the icon on the right is the new VSC icon:

[image]

---

#### New Visual Studio Code Icons Unveiled

> Risking the wrath of recalcitrant developers, Microsoft is changing the icon scheme for its Visual Studio Code editor.

...

> Last week, he updated the issue, unveiling new orange icons for Mac, Windows and Linux, with a slight variation for Windows Insiders.
>
> "We feel that the icon denotes 'openness,'" Dias said. "It conveys that VS Code is (in a good way) a subset of our big brother, the Visual Studio IDE. And, if you look hard enough, you'll find a small tribute to a great mind.
>
> "The new icons will appear in Insiders shortly and will be in Stable when we release the August iteration in early September."

Source [New Visual Studio Code Icons Unveiled](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/08/29/new-vs-code-icons.aspx)